# Is it possible to insert a timed pause into batch files?

Tags: batch-file

Is it possible to insert a timed pause in a DOS batch file?

It should act like the pause command, but instead of having to hit any key, it will continue on its own in X seconds.

Comment: To impress my girlfriend.

Comment: But seriously, I want to exceute shudown -r after a bunch of scripts have finished executing, don't ask why, and don't ask why I am not using shutdown -r -t X, it doesn't work for our purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ugly, but traditional, solution that I've seen used when you don't want to install any non-stock software is to use PING. Such as:

```
@echo off
rem Sleep 5 seconds
ping -n 6 127.0.0.1>NUL
```

The 6 is necessary because the first request is returned almost immediately, counting for roughly "0" seconds, so you need to send x + 1 more requests to get the desired delay.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're not talking about DOS batch files but Windows batch files:

```
> timeout /?
```

> **TIMEOUT** [/T] timeout [/NOBREAK]
>
> Description:
>
> > This utility accepts a timeout parameter to wait for the specified time period (in seconds) or until any key is pressed. It also accepts a parameter to ignore the key press.
>
> Parameter List:
>
> ```
> /T        timeout       Specifies the number of seconds to wait.
>                         Valid range is -1 to 99999 seconds.
>
> /NOBREAK                Ignore key presses and wait specified time.
>
> /?                      Displays this help message.
> ```
>
> NOTE: A *timeout* value of −1 means to wait indefinitely for a key press.
>
> Examples:
>
> ```
> TIMEOUT /?
> TIMEOUT /T 10
> TIMEOUT /T 300 /NOBREAK
> TIMEOUT /T -1
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean "batch" files. There's no built-in command; but the Win2003 Resource Pack included a program that functions the same. More info here: http://malektips.com/xp_dos_0002.html

Comment: If it is a batch file you can use the the choice command.  To wait for 3 seconds a command like `choice /t 3 /D N > nul` would work.

Comment: the choice command is not recognized :(

Comment: You think the sleep program would work on XP if I imported it?

Comment: @ToastMan, yes that program will work on Win2k to Win7.

Comment: The `choice.exe` seems to on every version of windows except XP.  I think it was added as part of DOS 6.0 if I remeber right.  You may be able to copy a choice.exe from a w2k box if you have one available.

Answer (score 0):

Or, you could do it this way:

```
@echo off
rem Sleep 5 seconds
CALL :TIMEOUT 5
ECHO Do other stuff here

GOTO :END

:TIMEOUT
ping -n %~1 -w 1 127.0.0.1>nul
EXIT /B 0

:END
pause
```